# how to sort a scala.collection.Map[java.lang.String, Int] by its values?

Tags: sorting, scala, scala-collections

How would you sort a scala.collection.Map[java.lang.String, Int] by its values (so on the Int)? What is a short and elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Depending on what the expected output collection type is (`SortedMap`s are sorted on the keys), you could use something like this:

```
Map("foo"->3, "raise"->1, "the"->2, "bar"->4).toList sortBy {_._2}
```

Result would be the list of key/value pairs sorted by the value:

```
List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((raise,1), (the,2), (foo,3), (bar,4))
```

There is a Map type that retains the original order, `ListMap`, if you apply this, you have a map again:

```
import collection.immutable.ListMap                                          
ListMap(Map("foo"->3, "raise"->1, "the"->2, "bar"->4).toList.sortBy{_._2}:_*)
```

Then you have:

```
scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[java.lang.String,Int] = Map((raise,1), (the,2), (foo,3), (bar,4))
```

(Scala 2.8)

Comment: +10, seriously useful, ListMap preserves order post-List-sort

Comment: what about descending order?

Comment: @vefthym `Map("foo"->3, "raise"->1, "the"->2, "bar"->4).toList sortWith {_._2 > _._2}`