# Play framework how to iterate with ordered index

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using play framework 2.3.8 and I need to iterate a java HashMap which I do like this in the template:

```
 @(city: String, intents: java.util.Map[Intent, TimeTable.Row], lang: Lang)

@for((item, index) <- intents.entrySet.zipWithIndex) {
            <li>Item @index </li>
        }
```

The problem now is that I got indexes as follows:

Item 7
Item 17
Item 22
Item 8
Item 28
Item 23
Item 33
Item 18
Item 5
Item 25
Item 11
Item 16

How is it possible to get ordered indices and why is the list here unordered?

Comment: You are trying to iterate using a Set, and it doesn't have any order in its elements. However you could change the type and order it by any inner property of the object.
You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972871/how-to-sort-a-scala-collection-mapjava-lang-string-int-by-its-values) for a solution.

Comment: @CarlosVilchez Thanks, it clarifies is it, but how can I convert the java util map to a list which can be used with index inside the template?

Comment: I don't think the template is the place for this type of tasks. I would convert it before sending it to the template to keep it simple. Do you really need to do it inside the template?

Comment: well we ended up using arraylist which does the increment properly

Answer (score 1):

Just clarifing [Carlos's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913252/play-framework-how-to-iterate-with-ordered-index#comment47948981_29913252)

You could use implicit scala to java convertion:

```
@import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

@(city: String, intents: java.util.Map[Intent, TimeTable.Row], lang: Lang)

@for(((intent,row), index) <- intents.toList.zipWithIndex) {
    <li>Item @index : <strong>@intent</strong> <i>row</i></li>
}
```

Comment: the index wasnt sorted. I got arbitrary index values

Comment: @dc10 Could you provide example of data input, solution's output and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [SortedMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap), and it's better not to transform your HashMap into something else inside the template, but use SortedMap from the start.